# Importing picture into Crystal Report goes wrong

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

[The inserted picture is on the left, the original one is on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjm7X.png)
I went to Photoshop to remove the background using the Magic Eraser tool. The background is removed.
[Removed background in Photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1wYZ.png)
However, when I insert the image into Crystal Report, it adds those weird white and black background around the image.
Does anybody perhaps know why?
Thank you in advance!

I tried removing the image from the Crystal Report, went back to Photoshop and removed background again, then exported as PNG again.
I tried changing the png to jpg.
None of them work:(

Answer (score 0):

A typical problem in using png files in a Crystal report is that transparent background shows up as black.

The image below demonstrates how changing transparent to opaque white solves the problem.

This on-the-fly process is using a Crystal User Function Library. But you can use a manual process to do the same.

[image: color mapping using a Crystal User Function Library]